# Reset password for 'postgres' on v9.3 (Win Srv)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, password

I'm trying to reset the password of the user 'postgres' on a postgres 9.3 installation, but have been unable to do so...

I've tried every combination in pg_hba.conf I could find online (ex. 'host all all localhost trust'), but when I run 'psql -U postgres' or try to connect via pgAdmin III it asks for a password. If I leave it blank I get an error saying 'psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied'

Running on a Windows Server 2012 machine.

We are suspecting a corrupt DB/filesystem by the way, so that might have something to do with it, but if you have any suggestions...

I just tried with

```
host all all localhost trust
```

at the top of `pg_hba.conf`, with everything else commented out. It complained about “no entry for host ::1”, so I added

```
host all all ::1/128 trust
```

Then I get the error

```
FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist
```

when running `psql -U postgres`. Nothing happens with `telnet localhost 5432`.

Comment: After changing `pg_hba.conf` did you restart the PostgreSQL server or use `pg_ctl reload`? As for corruption: Read and act on this *now*: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: I restart the postgres windows service after I edit the file..
I also set up a test server and installed postgres 9.3 on that with the same results. Could no reset the password.

Comment: What does `telnet localhost 5432` respond to you?

Comment: When you edited `pg_hba.conf`, did you put the new/altered line *first*? It needs to be, because the *first matching line is used*.

Comment: Just tried with 'host all all localhost trust' at the top, everything else commented out. It complained about no entry for host ::1, so I added 'host all all ::1/128 trust'. Then I get the error "FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist" when running 'psql -U postgres'. Nothing happens with 'telnet localhost 5432'

Answer (score 1):

Then you will have to start PostgreSQL in [single-user mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-postgres.html#APP-POSTGRES-SINGLE-USER). Stop the PostgreSQL service. Then, from `cmd.exe`, run

```bash
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\postgres --single -D C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data postgres
```

(You have to replace the path to the `postgres.exe` executable and to the data directory with the correct values.)

Then look for the name of the bootstrap superuser:

```
SELECT rolname FROM pg_authid WHERE oid = 10
```

And change the password for that user:

```
ALTER ROLE superuser_name PASSWORD 'new_password'
```

Then exit with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Now you should be able to start PostgreSQL normally and login with that user.

If you run into problems with that (for example, if `pg_authid` is corrupted), you might have to restore your backup.